# Changing origin in N-dimension sphere in Box-Muller algorithm

Tags: python

I am using the following code (Box-Muller algorithm) to generate points in n-dimensional sphere. I am struggling to change the origin from [0, 0, 0] to [0.5, 1, 2], for example.

```
import numpy as np

def getRandomSamplesInNSphere(N , R , numberOfSamples):
   
    randomnessGenerator = np.random.default_rng()
    
    X = randomnessGenerator.normal(size=(numberOfSamples , N))
    U = randomnessGenerator.random((numberOfSamples , 1)) 
    
    return R * U**(1/N) / np.sqrt(np.sum(X**2, 1, keepdims=True)) * X
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an N-tuple out at the end with the N dimensional coordinates.  For the specific case you presented, you can just add the offset to the final result

```
    return R * U**(1/N) / np.sqrt(np.sum(X**2, 1, keepdims=True)) * X + (0.5, 1, 2)
```

[image: offset3ddist2]